# difference between meta language and markup language?

Tags: html, xml, xhtml, language-design

I want to know the exact difference between markup language and meta language

As we know XML is extensible markup language but I read it is a meta language, 
so how can be define a meta language and a markup language ?

Comment: @Diodeus, There's no call for that.  There's obviously a language barrier here.  "Human language" is not necessarily English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Markup language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language):-**

> A (document) markup language is a modern system for annotating a
>   document in a way that is syntactically distinguishable from the text.
>   The idea and terminology evolved from the "marking up" of paper
>   manuscripts, i.e., the revision instructions by editors, traditionally
>   written with a blue pencil on authors' manuscripts. In digital media
>   this "blue pencil instruction text" was replaced by tags, that is,
>   instructions are expressed directly by tags or "instruction text
>   encapsulated by tags".

**[Metalanguage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metalanguage)**

> metalanguage is language or symbols used when language itself is being
>   discussed or examined.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language) In logic and linguistics, a metalanguage is
>   a language used to make statements about statements in another
>   language (the object language). Expressions in a metalanguage are
>   often distinguished from those in an object language by the use of
>   italics, quotation marks, or writing on a separate line.